# How to list all symbolic links in a directory

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, find, ls

I have a symbolic link in my `/var/www/` directory that links to WordPress. When I run the command `ls -la` from the `/var/www/` directory the link to WordPress doesn't show up. Is there a way to list all of the symbolic links that are in a directory?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can use `grep` with `ls` command to list all the symbolic links present in the current directory.

This will list all the links present in the current directory.

```
ls -la /var/www/ | grep "\->"
```

Comment: It will return false positive if you have a file containing "`->`". Try a simple `touch "foo->"`

Comment: why not `grep`ing with `^l`?

Comment: Nice!  → .bash_alias: `alias listlinks='ls -l --color | grep "\->"'` 8-)

Comment: Pass `-R` to `ls` to get recursive list.

Comment: Please, do not use `ls` for scripting. Also mentioned in other answers. More: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 475):

Parsing `ls` is a [**Bad Idea**®](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), prefer a simple `find` in that case:

```
find . -type l -ls
```

To only process the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls
```

<sup>Credits: [How do I make the shell to recognize the file names returned by a `ls -A` command, and these names contain spaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434155/how-do-i-make-the-shell-to-recognize-the-file-names-returned-by-a-ls-a-comman/434457#434457)</sup>

Comment: `find: Unknown argument to -type: 1`

Comment: @ahnbizcad: It's not `1` (one) but `l` (link)

Comment: Great answer! I adjusted mine to not descend down directory path like this:
    `find /<your_directory> -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls 2>/dev/null`

Thank you!

Comment: For only the current directory (i.e. **not recursive**) add `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: `| awk -F' ' '{ print $11 }' | sort -n` provides a tidy listing of the symlinks ready to export to a file.

Comment: @cig0 u do not need to use `awk`, u probably want just this: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type l | sort -n`

Comment: What does the `-ls` do at the end of the find commands?

Comment: @GabrielStaples from man find:  `-ls    True; list current file in ls -dils format on standard output.` Useful to see `./os-release -> ../usr/lib/os-release` in /etc rather than just `./os-release`

Comment: What if I want to check if a specific path is a symlink ?

Answer (score 12):

`grep` is your friend:

```
ls -lhaF | grep ^l   # list links
ls -lhaF | grep ^d   # list directories
ls -lhaF | grep ^-   # list files
```

This will list lines starting with "l" which represent Links in the perms column in place of `l` use `d` for directories and `-` for files

Comment: Just don't do anything with this method programatically since malicious filenames can end up injecting shell code. To be safe, one should use the `find` command with `-exec`, and if piping to `xargs`, use the null-character separator output flag of `find` combined with the null-character separator input flag of `xargs`.

Answer (score 9):

POSIXly:

```
find ! -name . -prune -type l
```

Comment: Can you explain the `!` in this context?

Comment: @MtlDev `!` negates the condition matching, here `! -name .` means matching everything except current directory.

Answer (score 4):

To view the symbolic links in a directory:

1. Open a terminal and move to that directory.
2. Type the command:

   ```
   ls -la
   ```

   This shall long list all the files in the directory even if they are hidden.
3. The files that start with `l` are your symbolic link files.

Comment: -1: [KasiyA's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/522066/158442) already covers this.

Comment: this also lists non-syminks.  Far better solutions that answer the Q already posted.

Answer (score 3):

This returns all symbolically linked items (both dirs & fns) in a directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -print | cut -c3- | grep -v "\#"
```

However, in order to distinguish between actual symbolically linked item types:

```
ls -lhaF | grep ^l | grep -v "\#" | cut -c42- | grep -v "/" | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Returns symbolically linked filename items only. And,

```
ls -lhaF | grep ^l | grep -v "\#" | cut -c42- | grep "/" | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Returns symbolically linked dirname items only.

Answer (score 2):

using zsh

```
ls -l *(@)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 david david 15 Nov 18 22:35 gvimrc -> /etc/vim/gvimrc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 david david 13 Nov 18 22:19 mydomains.php -> mydomains.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `ls -lai`,it will list all the files and subdirectories with corresponding inode numbers.You know files with same inode number are the links(hard or soft) and this solution also works for the symbolic links.

Comment: `ls -lai` does *not* show the same inode number for a file and its symbolic links. Unlike hard links, symbolic links have their own separate inode entries. [This is what it looks like.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8324844/)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with python as well:

```
$ python -c "import os,sys; print '\n'.join([os.path.join(sys.argv[1],i) for i in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]) if os.path.islink(os.path.join(sys.argv[1],i))])" /path/to/dir
```

Sample run:

```
$ python -c "import os,sys; print '\n'.join([os.path.join(sys.argv[1],i) for i in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]) if os.path.islink(os.path.join(sys.argv[1],i))])" /etc
/etc/vtrgb
/etc/printcap
/etc/resolv.conf
/etc/os-release
/etc/mtab
/etc/localtime
```

This can be extended to be recursive via `os.walk` function, but it's sufficient to use simple list generation for listing links in a single directory as I showed above.

Comment: Way over complicating when basic shell commands can already do this.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find below one liner bash script command to find all broken symbolic links recursively in any linux based OS

```
b=$(find / -type l); for i in $(echo $b); do file $i ; done |grep -i broken 2> /dev/null
```