# Problem with spaces in file names

Tags: command-line

I want to do something repeatedly on a list of files. The files in questions have spaces in their names:

```
david@david: ls -l
total 32
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 13 Mai  8 11:55 haha
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david  0 Mai  8 11:55 haha~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 13 Mai  8 11:55 haha (3rd copy)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 13 Mai  8 11:55 haha (4th copy)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 13 Mai  8 11:55 haha (5th copy)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 13 Mai  8 11:55 haha (6th copy)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 13 Mai  8 11:55 haha (7th copy)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 13 Mai  8 11:55 haha (another copy)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 13 Mai  8 11:55 haha (copy)
```

Now I want to stat each of these files:

```
david@david: echo '
for file in $(ls)
do
stat $file
done' | bash
```

(I use echo and a pipe in order to write multi-line commands.)

When I do that, it works correctly on those files that do not have any spaces in their names.  But the others...

```
stat: cannot stat ‘(another’: No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat ‘copy)’: No such file or directory
```

Changing `$(ls)` to `"$(ls)"` or `$file` to `"$file"` does not work. What can I do?

**Edit:**

```
echo '
for files in *
do
stat "$files"
done' | bash
```

does the trick! As I'm new to bash, I want to keep things as simple as possible - so nothing with trying to escape spaces, or using `xargs` or the solution with `read -r`, although they solve the problem.

As some have asked: Yes, using this instead of `stat *` is weird. But I just wanted to find a general way to apply the same command on a bunch of file names in bash, using a for loop. So `stat` could stand for `gzip`, `gpg` or `rm`.

Comment: what's wrong with `stat *`? (;-)

Comment: Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I just use stat as an example. :)

I want to collect file names with ls, and then use the results of ls in a bash loop.

Answer (score 12):

The multiple quote from the `echo '` is complicating the thing.

You can just use:

```
for f in *; do stat -- "$f"; done
```

But also

```
stat -- *
```

...and if you want to collect the files and then apply the command (why?) you can go with (but be careful with file containing new lines...(1))

```
for f in *; do echo "$f"; done | xargs stat --
```

...and if you want hidden files too, [just use `* .*` as a pattern, but then remember that `.` and `..` will be in the set](https://askubuntu.com/a/434169/16395).

As an aside, [you shouldn't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

---

(1) but if you have file names with newlines, you somewhat deserve it... ;-)

Comment: "and then apply the command (why?)" --> stat just serves as an arbitrary command, as I'm trying out how to do bash loops with file names. It could be gpg, gzip or whatever else.

Comment: @user258532 whatever the command, always use `for f in *; do command "$f"; done`. Never parse `ls`, certainly never do it in a `for ` loop and why use `echo`?

Comment: echo: Because I like writing the commands on multiple lines... :)

Comment: @user258532 Huh? Why would you need echo for that? Just hit enter and continue on a newline. If you end a line with an open quote or on one of `do`, `|`, `&&` etc, you can continue on the new line. Either that or use heredocs. No reason to use `echo` and it can also cause problems.

Comment: "Just hit enter and continue on a newline." Ouch. :-D Now my IQ is officially below 0 - you know, I'm really new to bash and things like that. But I actually earn my money with R (the statistical suite and scripting language).

Comment: @user258532 then you're a braver man (or woman) than I :). Bash basically works like R here; just like R, you can continue commands on the next line if you haven't given a complete command yet.

Comment: Sometimes I use a GUI, sometimes I write R scripts in an editor, so I never really had to deal with the problem of multiple-line commands in R. The But now I found out. Thanks. Regards from the brave, male and stupid scientist. :)

Answer (score 6):

On a side note: you can split long / complicated commands over multiple lines by adding a space followed by a backslash and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> everytime you want to start writing into a new line, instead of forking multiple processes by using `echo [...] | bash`; also you should enclose `$file` in double quotes, to prevent `stat` from breaking in case of filenames containing spaces:

```bsh
for file in $(ls); \
do \
stat "$file"; \
done
```

The problem is that `$(ls)` expands to a list of filenames containing spaces, and the same will happen also with `"$(ls)"`.

Even solving this problem, this method will still break on filenames containing backslashes and on filenames containing newlines (as pointed out by terdon).

A solution for both problems would be to pipe the output of `find` to a `while` loop running `read -r` so that, at each iteration, `read -r` will store one line of `find`'s output into `$file`:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read -r file; do \
    stat "$file"; \
done
```

Comment: and hidden files? :)

Comment: That will still fail on file names containing newlines. Just don't parse `ls`. Ever.

Comment: That's a good idea, and it works!

Comment: @user258532 no it doesn't. Seriously, just [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). There are better and more robust ways. You might also want to read this: [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985) for more details.

Comment: The problem here is not `ls`, it's `for` -- `for` iterates over (IFS separated) **words** given after the `in` keyword`

Comment: He, `find` was my idea ;)

Comment: @A.B.  Since OP didn't use `-a` in `ls` I originally didn't cater for that, altough now this is solved for other reasons

Comment: @terdon You're right of course, I was just reading the article linked by Rmano, it's fixed now.

Comment: you have my +1 :)

Comment: @glennjackman well yes, it's the combination of `for` and `ls`. `for f in *` would be fine, for example.

Comment: @Scott I don't think so, in fact you're absolutely right. I just wanted to match OP's arguable style of splitting commands, for the sake of an easy comparison. However indeed I should have pointed out the downsides of that method. Thanks, updated

Answer (score 3):

Use the good old `find`, works with hidden files, newlines and spaces.

```
find . -print0 | xargs -I {} -0 stat {}
```

or any other instead of `stat`

```
find . -print0 | xargs -I {} -0 file {}
find . -print0 | xargs -I {} -0 cat {}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a R guy, I already found a workaround in R:

```
filenames <- dir(); # reads file names into an array.
                    # It works also recursively
                    # with dir(recursive=TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
system(     # calls a system function
 paste(     # join stat and the file name
  "stat",
  filenames[i]
 )
)
}
```

I know, it's mad. I wish the output of `ls` would be easier to parse... R can deal with spaces, because dir() returns a quoted character value. Anything between the quotes is then a valid file name with spaces.

Comment: Don't bother (but +1 for effort! :). Just use `for f in *`, hit enter and continue on a new line: `do`, hit enter again, `stat "$f"`, enter again, `done` enter. That's a command split nicely on 4 lines and won't break on any kind of file name.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into other instances of whitespace issues in for loops, so the following (imo more robust) command is what I generally use. It also fits nicely into pipes.

```
$ ls | while read line; do stat "$line"; done;
```

You could combine this with `grep` or use `find` instead:

```
$ find ./ -maxdepth 2 | grep '^\./[/a-z]+$' | while read line; do stat "$line"; done;
```

Comment: Your first answer fails on filenames that contain backslash, or leading or trailing spaces.  Your second answer fails totally unless you add the `-E` option to `grep`, without which it won't recognize `+` in a regular expression.  Even then, it's a swing and a miss on this question, since your `grep` ***removes filenames containing spaces***.  It also removes filenames containing digits (numerals) and punctuation (e.g., parentheses), as the examples in the question do.  And that's not even mentioning filenames that contain newline or begin with ***`-`*** (dash).

Answer (score -1):

Instead, you can rename your files replacing the space with some other character such as underscore, so you get rid of this problem:

To do that easily run the command:

```
for file in * ; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}" ; done
```

Answer (score -2):

**This answer will solve the problem of parsing `ls` and take care of the backspaces and new lines**

Try this, it will solve your problem using Internal Field Separator IFS.

```
IFS="\n" for f in $(ls); do   stat "$f"; done
```

But Also you can eaisly solve it without need to parse ls output using

```
for f in *; do   stat "$f"; done
```

Comment: doesn't work for hidden files.

Comment: OP didn't ask for hidden files

Comment: I don't see why you need to modify `IFS` here: quoting the variable should be sufficient to prevent word splitting, surely?

Comment: for parsing `ls `.

Comment: For what is the downvote!!!

Comment: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6764/what-do-you-do-about-unexplained-downvotes

Comment: @A.B. I read this before but for myself I like to know why I've been downvoted. Is there is some problem in the answer so i can learn to correct my knowledge or what. anyway thanks for your link

Comment: @terdon Please notice that I answered before all others so I didn't copy anyone's solution

Comment: No, the `for f in *` (the only correct solution here) was added 9 minutes ago, well after Rmano's answer. You might not have copied with no attribution, but it sure looks that way. Anyway, the real problems are my other points.

Comment: @terdon I answered like that inside the IFS portion and you can check the initail answer before the edits. . I never copied anything from anybody here in this question....

Comment: Ah, yes indeed you did, my bad. OK, scratch point 2. Your original approach which saved IFS was slightly better (though `IFS="\n" for f in *; do ...` would have been simpler), but the main issue is that you are still parsing `ls` and that will fail on file names with newlines.

Comment: @terdon I have no problem when you say I'm wrong in my approach. I just don't like to say that i stole somebody effort... and thanks for your notes

Comment: You're absolutely right, that was an unfair accusation and based on my own misunderstanding. My apologies. I have now deleted that comment and reproduce my problems with your answer here: you're 1) suggesting parsing the output of ls. That won't work. Your solution still breaks on file names with newlines or starting with - (though the latter is easy to fix with stat --) ; 3) using an unnecessarily complex way of setting IFS; 4) Not setting IFS back again.